# Show large image of thumbnail on click but with multiple containers

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, thumbnails

Lots of similar questions have been asked on Stackoverflow. But after several days experimenting with the other solutions on here, I can't find any that match exactly what I'm trying to do.

I want to create a fixed size container that is always the same height from the top of the page and always the same margin from the left of the page. The container has thumbnails along the bottom (that will eventually have arrows on the right to scroll up/down - haven't got that far yet) and a larger image displayed above with information in a seperate box to the right side of the larger image. Every time a thumbnail is clicked, the larger image changes to display the larger version of the new thumbnail along with the corresponding information.

All the thumbnail images are 150 x 150. All the larger images are 300 x 300. The information displayed in the info box is the img alt text. The images are all stored in the same folder as the code and have the same file names with 'thumb' or 'large' changed. For example, 'image_01_thumb.png' or 'image_01_large.png'.

I have several existing elements on my page that are default to the entire site, that I believe are likely causing the issues.

```js
$('#thumbs img').click(function() {
  $('#largeimage').attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb', 'large'));
  $('#description').html($(this).attr('alt'));
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url(pic1.png);
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.main-nav {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 45px;
}

.main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.main-nav li.active a {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.main-nav li a:hover {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.logo img {
  width: 540px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}

body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.row {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}

#thumbs {
  padding-top: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#largeImage {
  padding: 4px;
}

#thumbs img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  padding: 4px;
}

#thumbs img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#description {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 230px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#panel {
  position: relative;
}

#gallery {
  position: absolute;
  height: 520px;
  width: 660px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 180px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>PROJECTS</title>
  <link rel="shorcut icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/png">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
  <script type="text/javascript" script src="portgrid.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="logo.png">
      </div>
      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="portabout.html">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="portprojects.html">PROJECTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="portconnect.html">CONNECT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- the image container -->
    <div id="gallery">
      <div id="panel">
        <img id="largeImage" src="image_01_large.png" />
      </div>
      <div id="thumbs">
        <img src="image_01_thumb.png" alt="TBN" />
        <img src="image_02_thumb.png" alt="Brain" />
        <img src="image_03_thumb.png" alt="AWG" />
        <img src="image_04_thumb.png" alt="Building" />
      </div>
    </div>

  </header>
```

Comment: What is the specific question here? It does not work? Or what is the blocking point? Can you provide a working sample?

Comment: The thumbnails and main image show up in place. However, the main image does not change when a new thumbnail is clicked on and there is no description appearing on the side.

I'm attempting to create a CodePen example, although that is causing entirely new errors.

Comment: @Sudoku Have you tried some simple debugging like adding `console.log($(this).attr('src'));` to your click function to double check the function is using the expected data?

Comment: @NewToJS - I just get "Object { https: false, httpsAutoUpgrade: false, privacyScore: 2, entitiesBlocked: {}, entitiesNotBlocked: {}, scores: null }" over and over in the console when I open the page.

Comment: I gave up trying to make the above work in the end and used an iframe from a seperate page to load the images. Got it working correctly in Firefox, which is a massive improvement!

Answer (score 0):

The code is ok, the problem is that you misspelled the large image ID on the Js, is #largeImage, not #largeimage

```
$('#thumbs img').click(function() {
    $('#largeImage').attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb', 'large'));
    $('#description').html($(this).attr('alt'));
});
```

Comment: I've tried using lowercase 'image' instead and it makes no difference.

Comment: This is what your are trying to achieve https://codepen.io/federicomartin/pen/xQEpqq ?

Comment: Yes, except the main image is twice the size of the thumbnails, there is a logo across the top left of the page (in line with the menu on the right) and the background image of the page stretches and resizes with the browser. I wondered if the logo or page background was causing the issues, but I can't change these as they are default to the entire website.

Comment: But the Js is ok?

Comment: Yes, the error still happens either way. I don't think it's the JS code itself that's the issue, but it's conflicting with something else on the page that's preventing the JS from doing anything. But I can't work out what that conflict is.

I'm not sure how to do it in CodePen, as I need 4 thumbnail images and 4 large images to show what is/isn't happening. The JS code should identify the thumbnail image clicked, then change the filename by swapping 'thumb' for 'large', then open the image with that filename and display it where the large image is.